# How to redirect a URL to another URL using /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, server, websites, hosts

I want to block some sites on my ubuntu system.So, I added some lines to the `/etc/hosts`, which are

```
127.0.1.1       www.reddit.com
127.0.1.1       www.facebook.com
```

This now successfully blocks the website but I want to redirect to another URL when I go to one of the URL I mentioned above, I found that you need to change the `127.0.1.1` to `IP of website`
to make it work but I can't convert URL such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XhMv.png to IP address.

It would be really helpful if someone can let be convert any URL to IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. Well, at least not how you are trying to do it.

In your desired URL (`https://i.imgur.com/6FxzzCT.png`), only this part has a specific IP address: `i.imgur.com`.

```
$ dig +short i.imgur.com
151.101.16.193
```

In a simplified form, when you enter that whole link in your browser (`https://i.imgur.com/6FxzzCT.png`). You are sending a request to `151.101.16.193` asking for `6FxzzCT.png` file using HTTPS protocol.

Using `/etc/hosts` you can only set predefined IP addresses per hosts but you can't handle HTTP requests.

What you might be able to do is to run a simple HTTP server on `localhost` serving a picture or a random picture at `index.html` or whatever predefined default page. Then redirect every site you like to `127.0.0.1` using `/etc/hosts`. Now your page is waiting there to bring up some random picture.